# Get upright bold for Greeks

Tags: fonts, greek

I use `lgreek` package for inserting Greek letter, there is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{lgreek}

\begin{document}

\section{\textup{\begin{greek} p\end{greek}}} 

\end{document}
```

Result quite fits me, but the warning appears:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LG/cmr/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available (Font)              
Font shape `LG/cmr/b/n' tried instead on input line 9.
```

I try to use `\fontseries{b}`, but the warning persists.
So, the question is: how to fix the code, so that the warning go away?

Comment: I would keep at arm's distance (at least) from `lgreek`.

Comment: @egreg And what instead?

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77341349/2777074

Comment: @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz 
Agree completely.
I realized postfaxtum that tex.stackexchange woulld be better place for this question. I've deleted the clone on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `lgreek`: it's buggy and useless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Україна

\textbf{\greektext{p}}

\greektext{Ελληνική Δημοκρατία}

\greektext{Ellhnik\'h Dhmokrat\'ia}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple way? Many thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: It really works, many thanks!